# A system of equations to find highest possible outcome

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to solve a really simple system of equations, but its been about 10 years since Ive done this stuff. Can someone explain how to choose which stocks to buy based on cost, projected return, and certainty about the outcome?

Question:

```
Stock Cost Certainty Profit_Potential
A     5    2         .3
B     3.5  1         .1
C     2    .5        .6
```

Some notes

- The certainty is simply relative. A certainty of 1 is average, .5 is half as certain as normal, 2 is twice as certain as normal.
- I have $1000 to invest

How do I maximize profits?

Comment: You are probably looking for a [linear program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) that maximizes expected profits (I assume certainty has something to do with expectation).

Comment: There are not enough information to answer the question.

Comment: What other information would be required? (Im very new to this)